# EasyMock: supplying arguments you don't know at compile-time

Tags: java, easymock

Using the latest version of EasyMock, I have a method that I need to stub out.  The method takes an object parameter and returns void.

The stubbed method is being called by the method I'm testing.  No surprises there.  My difficulty is that the object that is supplied as an argument to the mocked method is being created by the method I'm testing.

I know I can get around this using `createNiceMock()` but is there a way to explicitly stub out this method?

Sample code:

```
public interface IMockMe { 
    void doSomething(InnerObj obj);
}

public class TestMe {
    IMockMe mockMe; 

    public void testThisMethod() {
        InnerObj obj = new InnerObj();
        mockMe.doSomething(obj);
    }
}

class Tester {
    @Test
    public void testThatDarnedMethod() {
        IMockMe mocked = EasyMock.create(IMockMe.class);

        mocked.doSomething( /* what goes here? */);
        EasyMock.expectLastCall();

        TestMe testMe = new TestMe(mocked);
        testMe.testThisMethod();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the "Flexible Expectations with Argument Matchers" section of the [EasyMock documentation](http://easymock.org/user-guide.html#verification-expectations). Sample from the documentation:

```
String[] documents = new String[] { "Document 1", "Document 2" };
expect(mock.voteForRemovals(aryEq(documents))).andReturn(42);
```

The `aryEq(documents)` is a call which creates a matcher which will match any array with the right contents, rather than matching by identity.

In your case, you may want the [`anyObject()`](http://easymock.org/api/org/easymock/EasyMock.html#anyObject--) matcher.

Comment: Broken link.  Please see: http://easymock.org/user-guide.html#verification-expectations

Comment: would be great to add a code example, instead of referencing the site

Comment: @JessBowers: Have copied the example from the documentation and explained it a bit.

Comment: What if you have a void method and therefore no expect() ?

Comment: @PieterDeBie: You use `expectLastCall` instead of `expect`.

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks for the reply. I thougt that it was impossible to have void methods with anyXxx since it threw exceptions in my case. It seemed though that I wasn't using a mock object.

Comment: I think this won't work if voteForRemovals is a void method.

Comment: @user1821961: Well that syntax for setting up the return value won't work, but the argument matching part will - and that's what the question was about. For void methods, you'd call `expectLastCall` in a separate statement instead of `andReturn`.